# cleared floats pushing down

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've noticed an annoying thing with competing floats on opposite sides of the page.

I have two jsFiddles to illustrate my problem:

[Fiddle A](http://jsfiddle.net/drizztmainsword/gEet9/2/),
[Fiddle B](http://jsfiddle.net/drizztmainsword/gdFjy/2/)

In the Fiddle A example, you can see that the image on the left is at the top and at the same level of the green block. In this instance the green and blue divs are inside of a container:

```
<div class="floatContainer" style="float: right">
    <div>Green Div</div>
    <div style="float: right; clear: right;">
        Blue Div
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I have with this layout is that the text isn't wrapping tightly to the blue block, as it's wrapping around the container instead.

In the Fiddle B example, I managed to get the wrapping done correctly by not floating the container and floating the green and blue divs individually. In order to get the blue div below the green one, it of course has a "clear: right" tag on it.

However, you can see that the image on the left is now pushed down so that it starts at the same y-coordinate as the blue div, and that's not what I want.

So, is there a way to have the text wrap nicely around the green and blue div separately while still letting the leftmost image be positioned properly? This seems like a CSS bug, as it's certainly not the behavior I expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Move `.floatContainer` inside of `.content` so it is after the `<img>` so it does not get cleared.

```
<div class="content">
    <img class="right" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100" width="150" height="100">
    <div class="floatContainer">
        <div class="rightFloat">Stuff and things are long</div>
        <div class="rightFloat second">More Things</div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdFjy/3/

Comment: I would do this, but I'm not sure if that image is going to exist or not. This is for a blog page, and I want to make sure the design allows for any assortment of images.

If that's my only option, I'll just go with the first example.